# Can't install development files for QT on RPi Zero W

Tags: apt, qt

I've been following [this tutorial](https://wiki.qt.io/RaspberryPi2EGLFS) trying to get working QT cross-compilation from my PC to a Raspberry Pi Zero W.

It is failing on Step 5 ("*Install a bunch of development files*").

Running `sudo apt-get build-dep qt4-x11` results in this:

```
builddeps:qt4-x11 : Depends: debhelper (>= 9) but it is not installable
                    Depends: default-libmysqlclient-dev ...
                    ...
                    (similar "depends" error continues about 20 lines)
                    ...
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

A similar situation results when running `sudo apt-get build-dep libqt5gui5`.
Running `sudo apt-get install libudev-dev` reports `E: Unable to locate package libudev-dev`, and fails.

This is my `/etc/apt/sources.list` file:

```
deb http://mirrordetector.raspbian.org/raspbian stretch main contrib non-free rpi
deb-src http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian stretch main contrib non-free rpi
```

Comment: Did you run `sudo apt update` before trying to install packages? The repo source also seems to indicate that you either did not install an RPF Raspbian image or it has not been updated/upgraded for a long time

Comment: I did run `apt update`. It seems to work fine except for a line at the end: `E: The repository ... does not have a Release file.` I originally installed Raspbian from https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/ a few days ago, though I have edited the `sources.list` file from its original state, since this same error was occurring with the original sources.

Comment: Currently I am also facing the "E: The repository 'http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian stretch Release' does no longer have a Release file." message when running apt update. My guess is that currently there are some problems with the servers at raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian as the domain only shows me the Apache 2 Debian default page when visiting it.

Comment: Now there is also an open question regarding this error: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/93859/is-raspbian-stretch-repository-down

Comment: `though I have edited the sources.list file from its original state,` that's what I suspected. Current default is pointing to raspbian.raspberrypi.org. I would restore the default and try update / upgrade again. If that results in an error then update your question with that. No use in trying to install anything if you get an error during 'update'