# Is Raspbian stretch repository down?

Tags: raspbian, raspbian-stretch

I came to the office this morning only to be greeted by a whole bunch of puppet errors all over our device fleet.

Upon investigating, it seems none of the devices are capable of locating the raspbian stretch repository anymore. Running `sudo apt-get update` on any of them results in the following:

```
Get:1 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian stretch InRelease [25.4 kB]
Ign:2 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian stretch InRelease
Err:3 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian stretch Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 5.153.225.207 80]
Get:4 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian stretch/main armhf Packages [205 kB]
Get:5 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian stretch/ui armhf Packages [42.0 kB]
Reading package lists... Done                             
E: The repository 'http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian stretch Release' does no longer have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
```

This appears to be the case for devices running stretch all over the fleet. They are located in different networks and none of them have problems with connectivity, DNS resolution or similar. They're working fine.

The url http://raspbian/raspberrypi.org/raspbian does not resolve in a browser or in curl.
The url http://raspbian/raspberrypi.org shows the Apache2 default page, as if the server was set up but not configured. I have no idea if this is normal for that server, but I wouldn't expect so.

We have some older devices running Jessie, which doesn't seem to be affected so much, although requests to the same IP also fail:

```
Err http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie/main armhf Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 5.153.225.207 80]
Err http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie/contrib armhf Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 5.153.225.207 80]
Err http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie/non-free armhf Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 5.153.225.207 80]
Err http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie/rpi armhf Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 5.153.225.207 80]
```

I have not found an official support page for raspbian, I would be posting this there first if I had. As it is, posting this here and asking if other people are seeing the same behaviour seemed the best option.

Comment: `http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian` definitely a 404 at the moment - looks like it's been also reported on raspberry pi forum https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=63&p=1425880

Comment: by the way ... it's back up now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was my screwup sorry.

As part of preparing for a server upgrade that would require a reboot I disabled some cron jobs and changed the DNS settings in the early hours of the morning (UK time), sent an email to Mythic Beasts that they could go ahead with the reboot and then went to bed. Unfortunately there were some configuration errors on the server that I moved the DNS too which meant while it responded fine on it's test host name it did not respond correctly on some of the production host names.

Mythic noticed the problem soon after the start of business hours and executed a failover procedure which brought things back online (though not in an optimal configuration) until I woke up, figured out what was going on and sorted things out.

Answer (score 1):

To have an answer for the question, here is the comment from *@Jaromanda X*:

> http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian definitely a 404 at the moment - looks like it's been also reported on raspberry pi forum https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=63&p=1425880.

.

> by the way ... it's back up now.